# Solve inverse trig system

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

The problem is: Solve for $x,y$ in
$$\sin^{-1} x-\sin^{-1} y=120^{\circ}$$
$$\cos^{-1} x-\cos^{-1} y=60^{\circ}$$

My problem is that if

$$\sin^{-1} x+\cos^{-1} x=90^{\circ}$$ holds the system is impossible to solve.
By moving to the other side one can easily deduce that $x=\pm \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$ or possibly, $x=0$, same with $y$. But what is the correct solution ? I assume $\sin^{-1}$ is chosen between $-90^{\circ}$ and $90^{\circ}$, and that $\cos^{-1}$ between $0^{\circ}$ and $180^{\circ}$.

Comment: I don't understand. Do you have a valid solution pair $(x,y)$?

Comment: @MyMolecules No, I cant find one.

Comment: So since this system of equations contradicts $\sin^{-1}x+\cos^{-1}x=90^\circ$, there is no solution.

Comment: @MyMolecules Well, yeah, it seems so.

Comment: Where did you come across this question?

Comment: @Asher2211 It is on pg 96 of Hobson's Treatise on Plane Trigonometry. A good book but not without typos, so I assume there is some sense to the question.

Answer (score 2):

If you assume that $-90\leq\arcsin \leq90$ and $0\leq \arccos\leq 180$ there can be no solution because:
$$-90\leq \arcsin y\leq90\implies -90\leq\arcsin x-120\leq 90$$
$$\implies 30\leq\arcsin x\leq 210\implies \frac12\leq x\leq1$$
But on the other hand, $$0\leq\arccos y\leq 180\implies0\leq\arccos x-60\leq180$$
$$\implies 60\leq \arccos x \leq240\implies -1\leq x\leq \frac12$$

The only solution for $x$ is $x=\frac12$.

But then, the first equation gives $$\arcsin y=-90\implies y =-1$$ and the second equation gives $$\arccos y = 0\implies y=1$$

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer. Let us define the angles $\theta_s=sin^{-1}x$ and $\theta_c=cos^{-1}x$ and similarly $\phi_c$ and $\phi_c$ for $y$. The supplied equations become $$\theta_s - \phi_s = 120$$ and $$\theta_c - \phi_c = 60.$$ But we know that $\theta_c=\theta_s-90$ and $\phi_c=\phi_s-90$ so make those substitutions into the second equation to get $$\theta_s - \phi_s = 60$$ which is incompatible with the first equation.